# Golang, change the array by pointer

Tags: pointers, go

I have some arrays of different struct, and I need to change them by the same function `func foo(arr interface{})`.

And I use the function in this way `foo(&arrayToChange)`

Then I find that, I cannot change the array by pointer a [simple example](https://play.golang.org/p/siC8FZ4Zry) for you.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func A(out interface{}) {
    arr := make([]interface{}, 0)
    arr = append(arr, "foo", 2.2)
    out = &arr
    B(out)
}

func B(out interface{}) {
    arr := make([]interface{}, 0)
    arr = append(arr, "bar", "foo", "anything")
    out = &arr
}

func main() {
    arr := make([]interface{}, 0)
    arr = append(arr, 1, 2, 3)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", &arr)
    A(&arr)
    fmt.Println(arr)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess your question there is,
even though you do `out = &arr` inside the function,
how come `arr` in the caller is unchanged.

`out` is a local variable in your function.
You pass to the function `&arr`,
so the value of `out` is the address of `arr`.
And then you change the value of `out` to something else.
This affects nothing outside the scope of this function.
Reassigning the values of local variables never affects anything outside the scope of a function.

It seems what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
*out = arr
```

That is, change the value where `out` is pointing.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func A(out *[]interface{}) {
    arr := make([]interface{}, 0)
    arr = append(arr, 1, 2)
    *out = arr
}

func main() {
    arr := make([]interface{}, 0)
    arr = append(arr, 1, 2, 3)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", &arr)
    A(&arr)
    fmt.Println(arr)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer works on `[]int`. But I got **invalid indirect of out (type interface {})** when i try use it on `interface{}`. What I really want is to write a general function which can _set/update_ the **value** of a pointer.

Comment: Caused by the preconception that `[]interface{}` is illegal in Golang, 
I never once thought I can try `*[]interface{}`. It's just a little bit difficult to understand.